# Let $P_n$ be the vector space of polynomials with degree $\le n$, $T:P_n\to P_n$, $(TP)(t)=(tp(t+1))''$. Find bases for image and kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Problem: Let $P_n$ be the vector space of polynomials with degree $\le n$. Let $T:P_n\to P_n$ be defined by $(TP)(t)=(tp(t+1))''$. Find base for image and kernel.

My work:
Let first derivative:
$(t^2 p'(t+1))$ and second time we get:
$$T(p(t))\to t^3p''(t+1)$$
Let $B=(1,t,t^2,...,t^n)$ be base for $P_n$.

We know that derivative polynomial has one degree  less than begin polynomial. So just for $(1,t)$ $T(t)=0$ and $T(1)=0$ so just for $1$ and $t$ operator $T$ is zero for every $t$.
$$Ker(T)=(1,t)$$.
Looking image of linear operator we know that every polynomial we send to $T$ become two degree smaller. So our base for image is:
$$Im(T)=(1,t,..,t^{n-3},t^{n-2})$$ $r(T)=n-1$ and dim $Ker(T)=2$ which is ok by Rank–nullity theorem because $$\text {dim } P_n=n+1=2+(n-1)=n+1$$
Is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that $T:P_n\to P_{n+1}$ (nor $P_n$). For example, $(Tp)(t)=t^3n(n-1)(t+1)^{n-2}$, which leading coefficient is $n(n-1)t^{n+1}$.

Now, your calculus for $ker(T)$ is correct: $Ker(T)=\mathrm{span}\{1,t\}$. Therefore $dim(Im(T))=n+1-2=n-1$

Now, explicitely, if we take $p_k(t)=t^k$ ($k=0,...,n$) then $$(Tp_k)(t)=k(k-1)t^{3}(t+1)^{k-2}=k(k-1)\left(\binom{k-2}{0}t^3+\binom{k-2}{1}t^4+...+\binom{k-2}{k-2}t^{k+1}\right).$$

Can you finish?